# How to get the currently set sounds in android phone with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am currently working with an ionic 3 alarm app. What I want to achieve is to play the currently set alarm tone of the default android alarm app. There will be no option to set the alarm tone. Rather play the default sound of the android device which is set on the default alarm clock. How can I achieve that. Need a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

The alarm app is a native system app that varies according to device and manufacturer, I don't think you'll be able to determine the currently selected sound for the alarm. Certainly Cordova won't have permission to read such setting because it's on a totally different scope.